# Action on cosets

Tags: group-theory

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then:

1. The action of $G$ on $G/H$ if transitive because $(ba^{-1})aH=bH$

Now, let $\{g_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be left coset representatives of $H$ in $G$. Then:

2. If $g_\beta g_\alpha H=g_\gamma g_\alpha H$ then $g_\beta^{-1}g_\gamma\in g_\alpha Hg_\alpha^{-1}$.

So, if $H$ is normal in $G$, then under the hypothesis of (2), we have $g_\beta=g_\gamma$.

Therefore, if $H$ is both normal and of finite index in $G$, then:

3. For every $g_\alpha$ and $g_\beta$ there is $g_\gamma$ such that $g_\gamma g_\alpha H=g_\beta H$.

Is (3) still correct under the following weaker assumptions?

Option 1: $H$ is normal in $G$, but not necessarily of finite index.
 Option 2: $H$ is of finite index in $G$, but not necessarily normal.
 Option 3: No assumption on $H$.

Comment: What do you think? Do you have any initial thoughts or attempts at answering this question?

Comment: My 1,2,3 are my attempts. This is just something I've been thinking about for myself, not homework.

Comment: Yes under Option 1, No under Option 2.

Comment: Be more explicit about how (3) follows from (1) and (2).